# Django Model retrieval gives wrong type error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a template that has a button that posts just the button's name to a view which has the following code:

```
if request.POST:
    a = request.POST
    name = mymodel.objects.get(id = a )[0]
        return HttpResponse(name)
```

request.POST has the name of the button that submitted the post. THE error is: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'

However, when I do: `a = request.POST['name]`, django raises a no 'name' in post error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is you use a hidden field. A button isnt really a good way to move data.

Answer (score 3):

This returns a [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) (similar to a python dictionary) with the data in it
    request.POST

anyway

```
request.POST['name']
```

should work. 
I would say theres no key 'name' in it. pearhaps it is called 'id_name' or something like that.

Have a look a the content of the query dict with a debugger or with a print statement:

```
print request.POST
```

Comment: I followed ur QueryDict link and in my view.py put in this :
 `return HttpResponse(a.items())`

This printed out: (u'6', u'Delete').

Delete is the name of the button and 6 is the value. How do I flip these so I can use request.POST['Delete']?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following code is in your template: -

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" name="option_one" value="option_one">Option One</button>
    <button type="submit" name="your_second_option" value="your_second_option">2nd Option</button>
</form>
```

You could do this in your view: -

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('option_one'):
        #do your stuff
    if request.POST.has_key('your_second_option'):
        #do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, you are trying to get first object from a list, so it should be:

```
mymodel.objects.getlist(id = a )[0]
```